# Mass redirection in Nginx to an external host(s)

Tags: nginx, redirect, redirection

I have around 500-1000 URLs to do redirects over. I'm aware how to do it when redirects belong to the same host -- via nginx maps.

But how to do it when some of them are local, but others are external?

Comment: What do you mean by local and external? Give examples in your question. It may be just a case of specifying the full URL in the `map`.

Comment: @RichardSmith local means outside of this host, external means on the same host.